# What's the difference between OC xor and Java xor?

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, xor

I hava a question about  Java and OC  xor:

First xor, the second  Base64

In  java, the code :

```
     String  numberStr = ("123456");

    char[] array = numberStr.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (char) (array[i] ^ 1984);
    }
    String xorStr = new String(array);


    byte[] b = null;
    String s = null;
    try {
        b = xorStr.getBytes("utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (b != null) {
        try {
            s = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
```

the result is : 37Hfst+z37Tftd+2

In OC,the code:

```
    NSString *numberString = @"123456";
    NSData* bytes = [numberString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    int8_t * bytePtr = ( int8_t * )[bytes bytes];
    NSInteger totalData = [bytes length] / sizeof(int8_t);
    NSMutableString *finalString = [NSMutableString new];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < totalData; i ++){
    bytePtr[i] = (int8_t)(bytePtr[i]) ^ (1984);
    [finalString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",bytePtr[i]]];
    NSLog(@"encrypt data = %d", bytePtr[i]);
    }

    NSData *finalData = [finalString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *baseString = [finalData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

the  result  baseString is : w7HDssOzw7TDtcO2

why  the result  is different?  I just know  my  OC  code  is wrong !
Could someone  tell  me  the  correct answer ?

Comment: It makes little sense to use XOR between an 8-bit value (from the array) and a 16-bit value (1984) and store the result in an 8-bit variable. But it might help to replace `int8_t` with `uint8_t`. And your cast is incorrect. `(int8_t)(bytePtr[i]) ^ (1984);` should be `(int8_t)(bytePtr[I] ^ 1984);`.

Comment: I replaced  int8_t with uint8_t , and use   (uint8_t)(bytePtr[i] ^ 1984),but the result  still different

Answer (score 3):

You are not using types that are equivalent to each other.

From the Java specification:

> "The char data type (and therefore the value that a Character object encapsulates) are based on the original Unicode specification, which defined characters as **fixed-width 16-bit entities**. The Unicode Standard has since been changed to allow for characters whose representation requires more than 16 bits. The range of legal code points is now U+0000 to U+10FFFF, known as Unicode scalar value. (Refer to the definition of the U+n notation in the Unicode Standard.)"

In your Java code, you're iterating over 16-bit objects. In the OC code, you're iterating over 8-bit objects.

For an 8-bit Java primitive type, use `byte`.

Comment: Or, to make the Objective-C code match, use a UTF-16 encoding (either big or little endian so it matches Java) and use `uint16_t`.

Comment: I  tried to  replace  int8_t  with int16_t, but  the  result is  still different ! I just want  to  change  my  OC  code ! Could you  help me ?

Comment: You also have to change the string encoding/decoding method. You are using UTF-8 as the encoding/decoding mechanism, when the correct corresponding encoding would be UTF-16 (per specs: "The Java platform uses the UTF-16 representation in char arrays ").

Answer (score 1):

Given that a Java `char` is a 16-bit value, your Objective-C code is giving a different result because you are trying to use UTF-8 encoding and 8-bit values.

To make the Objective-C code work like the Java code, you need to work with 16-bit characters instead of 8-bit bytes.

```
NSString *numberString = @"123456";
NSMutableString *finalString = [NSMutableString new];
for (NSInteger c = 0; c < numberString.length; c++) {
    unichar char = [numberString characterAt:c];
    char = char ^ 1984;
    [finalString appendFormat:@"%C", char]; // Note C, not c
}

NSData *finalData = [finalString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *baseString = [finalData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Comment: You need to debug both the Java code and the Objective-C code, line by line. Make sure each value before using XOR is the same. Then compare the value after doing the XOR. Figure out exactly at what point the two sets of code give a different result. Update your question with the results of that comparison.

Comment: Thank you  for  your  answer !  Really !  The  result  is  same !

Comment: Are you saying that the code in my answer is working for you and you now get the same result as the Java code?